# Java: Can I create Generic-typed static classes?

Tags: java, generics

I'm working on a Quicksort algorithm in java, and I'm required to use arrays.

Right now, I want to make this algorithm support sorting any array of Comparables.

I've looked around, but most of the discussion and tutorials around generics are pretty confusing.  Simply put, I'm not sure how to make this work.  I've already confirmed that the Quicksort works with Integers, Strings, etc, so all I need to do is make it work with all comparables.  But my IDE is telling me that I "cannot make a reference to the non-static type T".  I'm not sure what this really means.

```
public class QuickSort<T extends Comparable<T>> {

public static void Sort(T[] A) {
    QuickSortRecursive(A, 0, A.length-1);
}

public static  void QuickSortRecursive(T[] A, int p, int r) {

    if( p < r ) {
        int q = Partition(A, p, r);
        QuickSortRecursive(A, p, q-1);
        QuickSortRecursive(A, q+1, r);
    }
}

public static int Partition(T[] A, int p, int r) {
    String x = A[r];

    int i = p - 1;
    for(int j = p; j < r; j++) {
        if(A[j].compareTo(x) <= 0) {
            i = i + 1;
            //swap A[i] with A[j]
            T tmp = A[i];
            A[i] = A[j];
            A[j] = tmp;
        }
    }
    //swap A[i + 1] with A[r]
    T tmp2 = A[i + 1];
    A[i + 1] = A[r];
    A[r] = tmp2;
    return i + 1;
}

}
```

In a nutshell, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: How do you call these methods/class?

Comment: Why do you think that you need it to be static anyway? As far as I see from your code, it doesn't need to be.

Comment: kocko, I would call these methods using, for instance, QuickSort.Sort(A);

Comment: Devolus, They don't need to really be static at all.  I was just using static methods out of convenience, like a utility class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh ... well ...

When designing a generic class like

```
class QuickSort<T extends Comparable<T>> { ... }
```

that simply means that *instances* of that class can (and should) be parameterized with concrete type parameters. For example you can declare

```
QuickSort<String> sorter = new QuickSort<>();
```

Static methods do not belong to instances, so these methods have no clue about the meaning of the type paramater `T`. You could make those static methods generic themselves:

```
static <T> void Sort(T[] A) { ... }
static <T> void QuickSortRecursive(T[] A, int p, int r) { ... }
static <T> int Partition(T[] A, int p, int r) { ... }
```

But that leads to some other errors. For example, you have the following line in your method `Partition`:

```
String x = A[r];
```

As the parameter `A` is type as `T[]`, the compiler does not allow the assignment of an array's element to a `String` typed variable (`T` could be anything). If you already know, that these are strings, why not simply declare

```
static int Partition(String[] A, int p, int r) { ... }
```

No need for generics here.

Additionally, OOP is all about objects (aka instances) and not about static methods which are a more procedural design. So simply remove the *static* keyword from all your methods and change the above mentioned problematic line to

```
T x = A[r];
```

Then everything is fine and you can use your class as following:

```
QuickSort<String> sorter = new QuickSort<>();
String[] strings = someStrings();
sorter.Sort(strings);
```

As a side note: The Java code conventions say that method and variable names should start with lower letters, so better name your methods `sort`, `quickSortRecursive`, and `partition`.

Comment: Thank you.  The String x = A[r] was a flop, I was adapting this from code I had written a few weeks ago so I missed the String.

Comment: One thing I'm a bit confused on: in your final code snippet, you instantiated 'sorter' as "new QuickSort<>();".  Why didn't you do new QuickSort<String> instead?

Comment: From Java 7 on, you do not need to duplicate the concrete type parameter as the compiler is able to infer this type. The `<>` is called the diamond operator and works only in _instance creation expressions_ (with the _new_ keyword).

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the generic type declaration on each of the methods instead of the class, for example:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void sort(T[] A)
```

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:

1. You are using static methods. Any reason? When are you going to tell QuickSort what the T type would be?
   Basically you can't use a class's generic type parameters in static methods or static fields. The class type parameters are only in scope for instance methods and instance fields.

For static fields and static methods, they are shared among all instances of the class, even instances of different type parameters, so obviously they cannot depend on a particular type parameter.

2. Code here:

   ```
   public static int Partition(T[] A, int p, int r) {
       String x = A[r];
   ```

Your array is generic type (T[]) and you are trying to assign value which would be of type T to String? You should probably be doing

```
public static int Partition(T[] A, int p, int r) {
    T x = A[r];
```

Comment: Would static methods not work?  I'm was just using them out of convenience, honestly.  Should I instead have a "Quicksorter" object to perform Quicksorts on arrays?

Comment: Yes that's right. Use Object of QuickSort to perform sorting operation.

Comment: Thank you.  I'm sort of a newbie at Object Oriented programming, is there any particular reason I should do this instead of using it as a static utility class?